# OpenRefine beginners question converting text document

Tags: text, openrefine

At the National museum for Photography in the Netherlands, we have a small importing issue which we are not able to solve ourselves.

The list is a sort of database from a bookcollector with book information, made in an era when a database program wasn’t available to my bookcollector. It has almost 7000 books in the list. It would be printed to be taken as printout to book markets and to decide if the book was already in possession of the collector. For humans it is quite clear how it is formatted but because of its inconsistencies we have some difficulty converting it to a table (which we can then import into a library database).

- [Example of text document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_7cB14hN6N0X6dGLSNdb6I3sAxbuJM61mYNWqkIBSc8/edit?usp=sharing)

-The smiley logo is the start of new record, 
black logo says, Yes I have it
white logo says, no, not yet (idea was with a pen it could be colored in on the print)
The logo can of course be changed to any letter combination with which we can filter later on.

First field is title, which is (sometimes) continued in second and/or more rows in the first column

On the right in the first row is the year of publication

There are some fields which are usually with a fieldname in front of it:

- ISBN
- Trefwoord (is keyword(s)
- Uitg. (is publisher)
- Tekst (is author)
- Red. (is editor)

-Then we have the participating photographers' names, which makes the formatting rather messy. Usually the photographers are in the second and third column. It can be from one photographer to up to 30 or so names and they are formatted as used in the book (so sometimes with full name and sometimes with only letters).
BUT,
quite often we also have photographers in the first column. They are then between title (or Tekst field content) and ISBN.

Fortunately the collector uses a [. ] quite consequent as a separator. How would you go about in OpenRefine? Preferably I would like to first split records and group them together, then start by making columns for every content with a fieldname in front. Put the second and third column in a lot of fields at the end, called photographer1 until photographerXX. And then clear the mess in the first column by hand. Is that the way to go? And would someone with more experience here, be so kind as to give us a starting hand by explaining how we go about.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow; Could you post a short sample of your data? I think that no one is able to solve a problem like this in his/her mind without launching Open Refine and loading some data. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but could not figure out how. I did attach an image with one page but understand that that is not enough. Sorry, im very new to this.

Comment: You can try to put your sample on something like Google Spreadsheet and add the link to it by editing your question.

Comment: Thank you, Ettore Rizza, I have tried to add a sample to a google doc. Unfortunately I have not made it into a spreadsheet, the formatting to an excel file was a nightmare. Best!

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps new to OpenRefine, but your question is pretty hard and requires advanced knowledge of the tool. :)

It seems to me impossible to extract the information you want other than by massive use of regular expressions.

To give you a glimpse of how to proceed:

1° Import your text files as a "Line based text file", so that the content will be in a single column.

2° From this single column, identify the lines starting with a ☻, by using a text filter on this character. From the filtered column, create a new column with "Edit column, add column based on this column". Name this new column record and remove the text filter. **Move the new column to the beginning.**

The result should look like this:

[image]

Now apply "Edit cells, Join multi-valued cells" to column 1 using a space as separator, in order to get this:

[image]

3° You can then start extracting information from your two columns.

- From the new "record" column, you can extract dates using this GREL formula in a "Add column based on this column" window:

  `value.find(/\d+[\.\]]?$/)[0].replace(/\D/, '')`
- From the main column 1 you can extract the "Trefwoord" with:

  `value.find(/Trefwoord:.+?\./)[0].split(":")[1]`
- Same thing for ISBNs, etc.
- Titles will be more difficult to extract because it will be necessary to separate those that fit in one line and those that continue on the next line. This will require more complex GREL formulas.
- There are several possible strategies for extracting the names of photographers.
- Keep cleaning until you feel the quality is correct, knowing that it will probably not be 100 % perfect.

Comment: Wow Ettore Rizza, I understood this was quite complicated, but you helped us a lot. Thank you very much! I will try to work with your explanation and keep you posted. It is not necessary for us to do everything with OpenRefine but this will make the amount of hand editing a lot more doable.